# How to create common entities for RDBMS and MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot RESTful service that interacts with H2 RDBMS. 
I've decided to extend it by adding MongoDB support and to create two profiles, each for each data source.

My intention is to use common entities so I've started with changing `id` fields from `Long` to `BigInteger` because if I use `String` as `id` it will cause performance troubles with SQL insertions.

```
@Document
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public final class Book {

    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private BigInteger id;

    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Author author;

}
```

And, of course, corresponding repositories too.

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, BigInteger> {}
```

I also modified the H2 tables by substituting BIGINT type by BIGDECIMAL and refilled my tables. I have `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-aeuto=validate` in my properties and Hibernate validation complained to match `java.math.BigInteger` with `BIGINT` from db.

After all, I debugged my app but all the methods belonged to repository return empty results even `findAll()`, but I see that records are presented in tables and `"SELECT * from 'table'(e.g. BOOK)"` returns all records.

Could you clarify me some questions?

Is it a good way to combine JPA's and MongoDB's entity in one class? Does Spring Data work fine with BigInteger? Any hints?

UPDATE:
I've tried to start from the scratch and I found that after annotating entities with @Document annotation CRUD repository starts to misbehave and fails with org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException on methods annotated @Query(native=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you'd better avoid it and create two completely different projects/branches.

In this particular case you have designed your RDBMS solution well but to gain the more advantages from MongoDB you have to think twice about documents/collections hierarchy and consider nested documents.

Try to avoid joins in MongoDB. They cost very much